# Path for assets in DXA 1.7

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-1.7

## Edited as per Bart's comments

I left the default images path and URL for Publication as `/images` and `\images` in Web 8.5. However, I observed that all images are assumed to be pages and are processed by Page controller by adding an `/index` at the end.

But when I changed the images path to start with `/media` on the publication properties, things work.

Any specific reason why this keyword "media" has to be used always in publication properties if we are using DXA 1.7?

Where can we change this behavior to configure our own paths?

I am defining the image paths on publication properties and not in Topology manager.

Comment: Can you edit your question and indicate whether you are using Topology Manager or the legacy publishing model?

Comment: DXA shoukd work perfectly well with other Multimedia URLs than `/media` (we are using that ourselves on our test systems). Check the `mediaRoot` property in `BinaryData\xxx\system\config\_all.json`.